# Hasn't He vs Didn't He?

Tags: tag-questions

I am teaching a student English and the below question was in his test paper. I intuitively feel that both options one and two are not incorrect, but his answer key states that option one is the correct one. Which is the correct one and why?

> [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgPdz.png)
>
> "Tom gave up looking just as I said he would, _____?" Geetha asked.
> (1) didn't he
> (2) hasn't he
> (3) hadn't he
> (4) wouldn't he

Comment: 'Hasn't he' would only work if the sentence began 'Tom _has given_ up looking'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb in a tag question is a callback to whatever verb was previously used, implied, or what would fit.

For example:

> He **went**, **didn't** he?

"Went" is the *past* tense of *to go*, so he ***did** go*, therefore you would ask "**didn't** he?"

---

In your example, it says "Tom **gave** up". As "gave" is the past tense of *to give*, Tom ***did** give up*, so "didn't" is the correct verb contraction to use in your tag question.

Note that, should it have said "Tom ***has given up***", the correct choice would have been "**hasn't** he?"